# Is there a way to generate c code for system function which runs batch file?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, code-generation

I am trying to run a batch file which eventually runs an exe file. I am trying to use system function to run this batch file.Here is my MATLAB function which executes system command.

```
function y = run(u)
    y = system('C:\Users\Tester\Desktop\Release\meter_app.bat')
end
```

I have named this file as run.m. When I try to build the model, MATLAB coder throws an error saying that
 **"Function 'system' is not supported for code generation. Consider adding coder.extrinsic('system') at the top of the function to bypass code generation"**
 Is there a way to generate c code for system function or is there a way with which I can run a batch file which will be supported by code generation?

Comment: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  What code generator are you using?

Comment: This is really hard to follow. Please clarify. You say you have a MATLAB M-file that runs an executable through `system`, and that you want to generate C code for this M-file?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message advises?

Comment: It doesn't advise anything.But what I have understood from it is I have some how include it in the simulink model.https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/incorporate-c-code-using-a-matlab-function-block.html this is just what I am trying to follow. But I am not sure how to integrate with rest of my model.

Comment: "Consider adding coder.extrinsic('system') at the top of the function to bypass code generation" is advice.  Try following that advice.